# What does this -> ~T() do?

Tags: c++

Can anyone explain what this code extract is doing? My first guess was that `d()` calls the destructor of itself but then I wondered why you couldn't just call the destructor of `T` yourself.

```
class T
{
    void d()
    {
        this -> ~T();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That *explicitly* calls the destructor for `T` on `this`. The name of the destructor for `T` is `~T`.

Usually this isn't necessary, as C++ takes care of calling the destructor for an object when it goes out of scope or when you `delete` it. Without more context it's hard to say what is going on in your code and why the author thought that was necessary.

Comment: When you absolutely, positively need to destroy _this_.

Comment: @rrhartjr: Why not make an explicit `destroy` method then that's also called by the destructor? That's be much less hacky and magical, or am I missing something?

Comment: @NiklasB. I don't know, might want to consult the OP. I just write the sass.

Comment: @rrhartjr: Sorry, your comment sounded to me like a recommendation :)

Comment: @rrhartjr `this->~T()` does *not* destroy `this` -- it merely *destructs* `this`.

Comment: @Greg, will this ever throw an exception?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: Yes, a class destructor may throw an exception.

Comment: @GregHewgill, In what situations would that be?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Destructors may throw exceptions, just like any other code: `class T { ~T() { throw exception(...); }; };`

Comment: @GregHewgill, Sorry I meant could `this -> ~T();` ever cause an exception, not the destructor itself.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: Yes, if `this` is not a valid pointer to an object of type `T` (for example, if the destructor has *already* been called).

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.

`d()` is calling the destructor, and one could also call the destructor directly.

**Keep in mind that this does not restore the memory** as a call to `delete` would.

Answer (score 1):

Should I explicitly call a destructor on a local variable?

No!

The destructor will get called again at the close } of the block in which the local was created. This is a guarantee of the language; it happens automagically; there's no way to stop it from happening. But you can get really bad results from calling a destructor on the same object a second time! Bang! You're dead!

More details - http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.1

Comment: How do you know it is being used in the context of a local variable? If you use placement new, you need to call the destructor explicitly. I have no reason for declaring a member function for it though.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like it calls the destructor for the current class... it's weird to do that, basically it 'resets' the object if the destructor is properly written... but usually you will have to re-instantiate the member variables as well.